# Python Pokemon Battle - pokemon attack twice in one turn

Tags: python-2.7

I'm sorta new to python. I'm trying to make a pokemon battle. But i can't seem to figure out why whenever you attack and the enemy attacks, they attack twice. It should work like this:

*battle starts

*you attack enemy

*enemy attacks you

*one of you faints

```
import time
import random

# pokemon beginning battle
print "mewtwo has appeared"
time.sleep(1)
print "lvl 70"
time.sleep(0.5)
print "HP 128"
print " \n "

# Mewtwo stats
mewtwo_HP = 128
mewtwo_atk = 20
mewtwo_atk2 = 45
move = random.randrange(-1, 1)

# Lapras stats
attack1 = ['hydro pump']
attack2 = ['ice beam']
lapras_HP = 100

attack1range = random.randrange(15,32)

attack2range = random.randrange(20, 25)

run = "you can't run away!"
pokemon = "Lapras"

# Lapras's turn
while True:

    print "Lapras's moves:"
    print "[ice beam][hydro pump]"

    B = raw_input('> ').strip()
    Battle = B

    if Battle in attack1:
        print "Lapras used Hydro pump!"
    mewtwo_HP -= attack1range
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print "Mewtwo has", + mewtwo_HP, 'HP!'

    if Battle in attack2:
        print "Lapras used Ice beam!"
    mewtwo_HP -= attack2range
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print "Mewtwo has", + mewtwo_HP, 'HP!'

# Mewtwo's turn
    if move == 0:
        lapras_HP -= random.randrange(21,27)
        time.sleep(1)
        print "Mewtwo used Psystrike!"
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print "Lapras has", + lapras_HP,'HP!'
    else:
        lapras_HP -= random.randrange(19, 35)
    print "Mewtwo used Psywave!"
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print "Lapras has", + lapras_HP,'HP!'





    if mewtwo_HP <= 0:
        print "Mewtwo fainted!"
    if lapras_HP <= 0:
        print "Lapras fainted!"
        print "you lose!"
```

And if you have any suggestions to make my code better that would be great (:

Comment: Indentation is important in Python.

Answer (score 0):

The print statements you included didn't have a brackets in them and there was no indicator for a change in turns at the end of the attack. Here's what I created with the Lapras and mewtwo having an equal chance of going first. If you want to change this, you can just change the turn variable at the start to either 0 or 1.

```
import time
import random

# pokemon beginning battle
print("mewtwo has appeared")
time.sleep(1)
print("lvl 70")
time.sleep(0.5)
print("HP 128")
print("\n")

# Mewtwo stats
mewtwo_HP = 128
mewtwo_atk = 20
mewtwo_atk2 = 45
turn = random.randint(0, 2)
mewtwo_move = random.randint(0, 2)

# Lapras stats
attack1 = ['hydro pump']
attack2 = ['ice beam']
lapras_HP = 100

attack1range = random.randrange(15,32)

attack2range = random.randrange(20, 25)

run = "you can't run away!"
pokemon = "Lapras"

# Lapras's turn
while True:
    if turn == 1:

        print("Lapras's moves:")
        print("1. hydro pump")
        print("2. ice beam")
        choice = int(input())


        if choice == 1:
            print("Lapras used Hydro pump!")
            mewtwo_HP -= attack1range
            if mewtwo_HP < 0:
                mewtwo_HP = 0
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print("Mewtwo has", + mewtwo_HP, 'HP!')

        elif choice == 2:
            print("Lapras used Ice beam!")
            mewtwo_HP -= attack2range
            if mewtwo_HP < 0:
                mewtwo_HP = 0
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print("Mewtwo has", + mewtwo_HP, 'HP!')

    # Mewtwo's turn
    elif turn == 0:
        if mewtwo_move == 0:
            lapras_HP -= random.randrange(21,27)
            if lapras_HP < 0:
                lapras_HP = 0
            time.sleep(1)
            print("Mewtwo used Psystrike!")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print("Lapras has", + lapras_HP,'HP!')
        elif mewtwo_move == 1:
            lapras_HP -= random.randrange(19, 35)
            if lapras_HP < 0:
                lapras_HP = 0
            print("Mewtwo used Psywave!")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print("Lapras has",lapras_HP,'HP!')
    mewtwo_move = random.randint(0, 1)
    if turn == 0:
        turn = 1
    elif turn == 1:
        turn = 0




    if mewtwo_HP <= 0:
        print("Mewtwo fainted!")
        print("You win!")
        break
    if lapras_HP <= 0:
        print("Lapras fainted!")
        print("you lose!")
        break
```